# Changing an instance variable through a method

Tags: python

I am quite new programming and have been learning Python, i decided to try and create a text-based adventure through OOP, so far I've managed to overcome issues on my own but I'm stuck on this one problem i just cannot solve, here's the code:

```
class player:
    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health

Player_1 = player ('Bob', 80)

class enemies:
    def __init__ (self, description, health, damage):
        self.description = description
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage

    def __str__ (self):
        return '{} , {} , {}'.format (self.description, self.health, self.damage)

    def enemy_damage (self):
        Player_1.health - random_enemy1
        return Player_1.health

random_enemy1 = enemies ('Goon', 40, 5)
```

At the moment I'm just testing this code before applying it fully in the game, when calling the enemy_damage method (random_enemy1.enemy_damage) i can successfully lower the players health by 5, but the issue is that the players health isn't updated, so the next time the enemy_damage method is run, the players health is back to 80.

Can someone please help? How would i get the players health to update here? I have looked at numerous videos and whatnot about class methods etc but cannot wrap my head around this, i know the code is probably terrible for what i'm trying to do, but i'm just looking to get the thing to work at the moment, after which i will use other means to reduce the amount of code and improve on it.

Many thanks

Comment: You'll have to pass the instance (`Player_1`) to `enemy_damage` as an argument.

Comment: `Player_1.health - random_enemy1` doesn't update `Player_1.health` (and actually it should even raise a TypeError).

Answer (score 1):

You can define `enemy_damage` like this:

```
def enemy_damage(self, enemy):
    enemy.health -= self.damage
    return enemy.health
```

Then use it like this:

```
print("Player_1's health before damage: " + Player_1.health)

Player_1 = player('Bob', 80)
random_enemy1 = enemies('Goon', 40, 5)
random_enemy1.enemy_damage(Player_1)

print("Player_1's health after damage: " + Player_1.health)
```

Aside from that, I would recommend using one common class for both enemies and players, named `Player`.

According to PEP8, class names should normally use CapWords convention. See the docs [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names).